# push in javascript not working in IE6 but working in ie8

Tags: javascript

i have the following snippet and push function works fine in ie8 but not in ie6 and i cant able to get any solution regarding it.

kindly help me with it

Comment: I guess your code should be fine. Test it in fiddler.net.

Comment: What does the `#` sign in JavaScript do? I am confused.

Comment: That shouldn't work at all given the illegal `#` characters used when setting `tempData`.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati fiddler.net shows error content and the site is not opening.do u know any other such websites?

Comment: @AlvinWong hi Alvin ,it just works fine in IE8 ,i split that data later with # ,and while splitting its fine too.only while pushing there s a problem only in IE6

Answer (score 2):

Given that `#` is not a valid character for variable names, I'd guess that you forgot to add quotes around the value being set in `tempData`:

```
var tempData='RS_TIM_ENABLE#RS_TX_TRACE_MSG_ASIDE#EQ#ON';
```

Comment: even aftwer giving quotes it doesn't work

Comment: is it same with the updated post?

Comment: @user1752557, your updated post doesn't show any code.